# UIHostingViewController background color showing

Tags: swiftui

I am showing a UIViewController via a SwiftUI view, like so:

```
@available(iOS 13, *)
struct WelcomeNavView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WelcomeNavView>) -> UINavigationController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcomeNav") as! UINavigationController
        return navVc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WelcomeNavView>) {
    }
}
```

I then present it from a ViewController like so:

```
self.viewController?.present(style: .fullScreen) {
    WelcomeNavView()
}
```

However, it does not occupy the entire screen and the UIHostViewController color is showing at the top and bottom:

[image]

How can I change the color of the UIHostingViewController's view.. Or expand the View it is holding to occupy the entire screen?

Comment: Would you show what is `viewController` and what `present` does in this case?

Comment: @Asperi In the provided image you can see the viewController is presented, but it does not extend to the top and bottom safe areas. And thus the white color of the HostingViewController's view is visible.

Comment: @vikzilla how did you manage to remove white ui hosting controller??  Is it resolved?

Answer (score 6):

Another simple and quick solution is, you can ignore safe area of your `WelcomeNavView()` while presenting.

example

iOS 13:

```
WelcomeNavView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

iOS 14 and above:

```
WelcomeNavView().ignoresSafeArea()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution,
I ran into similar problem, wherein I had to set hosting view controller's background clear.

Apparently, *rootView* (probably our SwiftUI View) of hostingVC and hostingVC.view are different.

so this would allow you to change to background color.

```
hostingVC.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Of course use any color in place of ".clear".

Just keep in mind to change color of SwiftUI view passed as rootView to hostingVC accordingly, mostly make that clear, so it won't be shown against above set color.

```
Your_SwiftUI_View.background(Color.clear)
```

Comment: How do you access hostingVC?

Comment: You create HostingVC instance when you add you SwiftUI view to UIkit VC right? There only you do this.

Comment: @ImShrey,  in above case we are not creating UIHosting ourself. As in above case we are creating UIViewControllerRepresentable but UIhosting is created automatically underneath